# Solving the time an object takes to accelerate upwards taking gravity into account

Tags: math, gravity

I have an character in a game that can jump; the jump height can be affected by holding down the jump button for a longer time. There is a maximum velocity the character can reach in the upwards direction, and I am trying to figure out how long the longest jump can be taking gravity into account.

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with SUVAT equations as the object is accelerating, but I can't seem to work gravity into the equation. Here are the variables I'm working with...

```
JumpVelocity = 2.0,
JumpAccel = 0.5,
JumpMax = 7.5,
Gravity = -14.0,
```

as soon as jump is pressed an initial velocity is set...

```
yVelocity = JumpVelocity;
```

and then every frame the jump button is held the velocity is increased until it reaches the cap

```
if (!jumpFinished)
{
    yVelocity += JumpAccel; 
    yVelocity += Gravity * deltaTime;
    if (yVelocity >= JumpMax) 
    {
        yVelocity = JumpMax;
        jumpFinished = true;
    }
}
yVelocity *= deltaTime;
```

I check to see if the jump is finished with:

```
if (yVelocity <= 0.0)
```

What I want to solve is how long the whole upwards phase of the jump process will take if the user were to max-out the jump velocity?

Comment: Would you explain the f as in JumpVelocity = 2.0f, etc.

Comment: ahhh sorry they are float values the code is from C#. They can be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You let the initial velocity be increased while pressing, with the character already moving, so you have 2 differente stages:

**STAGE 1**

An initial positive acceleration, your character accelerate, sort of rocket or jetpack.

Initial conditions (t=0 of this branch):

```
v0   = JumpVelocity
vmax = JumpMax
a    = Gravity + jaccel 
r0   = 0 (initial height)
```

note that `jaccel` is not `JumpAccel`. Given your code `JumpAccel` is the variation of velocity in `deltaTime` time. So the actual *burst* acceleration is `jaccel = JumpAccel/deltaTime`. (USEFUL: for completeness - provide `deltaTime`).

This line in your code makes no sense to me: please explain.

```
yVelocity *= deltaTime;
```

Now you want to know *when* `v`, the velocity, reaches `vmax`. Given:

```
v = v0 + a*t
```

you want to find the value of `t` at which `v=vmax`. So you substitute and solve for t:

```
vmax = v0 + a*t
t = (vmax - v0)/a
```

or, using your symbols:

```
t = (JumpMax - JumpVelocity)/(Gravity + jaccel)
```

From `t` you can now evaluate the height that you have reached when you are at the maximum velocity. Get this [kinematic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion):

```
r = r0 + v0*t + 0.5*a*t*t
```

and substitute all the variables to get `r1`, the position at the end of the thurst.

```
r1 = 0 + JumpVelocity*t + 0.5*(Gravity + jaccel)*t*t
```

**STAGE 2**

The character continue decelerating until reaches the maximum height, that's what you want to know.

In this second problem we "move" the time origin here, where the first stage has just completed, so we are at t=0 again (this cannot be applied in the graph - the coordinate system is only one there... few more subtractions because of this in the gnuplot commands below). Forget about the previously evaluated t - its out of scope now. Our current initial conditions are:

```
v0   = JumpMax
a    = Gravity
r0   = r1, r evaluated at the previous stage
```

Now you want to find the value of `t` when `v=0`. So, using again:

```
v = v0 + a*t
```

substituting `v = 0` and solving for `t`:

```
0 = v0 + a*t
t = -v0/a
```

That using your variables (no symbols substitutions as shown before - easier to follow and you can evaluate it actually):

```
t = -JumpMax/Gravity
```

replacing `t` in the [kinematic equation with constant acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion), in order to find the position at that time (the time of the maximum height!):

```
r = r0 + v0*t + 0.5*a*t*t
```

that, using your variables is:

```
rmax = r1 + JumpMax*t + 0.5*Gravity*t*t.
```

That's it: `rmax` is the maximum height reached by your character.

To conclude, I have enjoyed to plot the two functions using gnuplot - it's available for free for both linux and windows, so you can play with it.

In the graph you can get the position at the various timesteps (each point is at a subsequent timestep, being plotted the height, r, versus the time, t). The two arrows point to `r1` and `rmax`, evaluated using the formulas obtained above (see the gnuplot commands)

[image: plotted with gnuplot]

Here the gnuplot commands to generate the graph - good luck!

```
unset key

JumpVelocity = 2.0
JumpMax = 7.5
Gravity = -14
jaccel = 30

const_acc(t,r0,v0,a) = r0 + v0*t + 0.5*a*t**2

t1 = (JumpMax - JumpVelocity)/(Gravity + jaccel)
r1 = const_acc(t1, 0, JumpVelocity,Gravity+jaccel)
t2 = -JumpMax/Gravity + t1
rmax = const_acc(t2-t1, r1, JumpMax, Gravity)

set arrow from t1,0 to t1,r1
set arrow from t2,0 to t2,rmax

set xlabel "t" 
set ylabel "r" 
set xrange [ 0 : 2 ]
set yrange [ 0 : ]

plot x <= t1 ? const_acc(x,0,JumpVelocity,Gravity + jaccel) : 1/0 w p, x >= t1 ? const_acc(x-t1, r1, JumpMax, Gravity) : 1/0 w p
pause -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks very promising, the only issue is I don't really understand it. It sounds like you understand what I'm trying to do though. What does "the first with your numerical integration" mean? Are you saying I need to do the equation twice, once for the acceleration and once for gravity?

Comment: if you want to evaluate also the button-pressed/burst phase analytically, yes - I will edit my question if this is the case - but keep in mind that the analytical result will be different from the numerical one. The numerical integration is "and then every frame the jump button is held the velocity is increased until it reaches the cap" with the code that follows.

Comment: I think it's because we are talking in different languages! I don't really have any background in maths and kind of fudge it as I go :)

Comment: I have used the following equation before to figure out how far something has travelled taking acceleration into account...

time = (initialV - maxV) / acceleration;
distance = (maxV * time) + (0.5 * acceleration * POW2(time))

is it a reverse of that equation? I also dont understand phases like "if you want to evaluate also the button-pressed/burst phase analytically" I understand what it is to evaluate and I know what you mean by the burst phase, but what is meant by analytically? I also understand the word analyse, just not in this context.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time with me! If you just disappear without a reply due to the magnitude of my ignorance I completely understand!

Comment: Like in the first equation where does t come from? As I'm trying to work that out. My head hurts. Sorry.

Comment: :) that's a lot of stuff... t is just "time" - that's kinematics, as in the wikipedia page. saying `v = v0 + a*t` means that the velocity at a given time `t` is `v0`, the velocity at time `t=0` plus the acceleration (a) multiplied by t - `time`: velocity constantly increase (or decrease if a is negative as in your case). http://physics.info/kinematics-calculus/

Comment: But I don't know the time, that's what's confusing me. :)

Comment: you have time in your code: it starts being "t=0" at the beginning (that's just a convention) and you increment it of `deltaTime` at each frame. In my answer I used it as the "glue" linking equations, that "analytics": forgetting the physical meaning of quantities to perform mathematical/symbolic operations. You have correctly used it numerically, but to get max height you need either to simulate it, or evaluate with some math operations as I've shown. You probably lack this knowledge - being very young or needing to study more. Don't be afraid: you can learn it! I will complete the answer.

Comment: be patient - this evening - now I cannot do it. thanks for accepting it in advance!

Comment: that's completed now. I hope it's clearer! Good luck!

Comment: WOW! Just wow! Thank you soooo much! I will endeavour to get this working, can't fail now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic equation you need is v=u+at, where u is initial velocity, v the velocity after time t, and a the acceleration. You appear to have two accelerations, that of the character and that of gravity. These combine to give one acceleration of -14 + 0.5 = -13.5

When v = 0

t= -u/a

Comment: Thanks for the response. Doesn't that equation solve for velocity? I want to know how long it will take to reach a velocity of 0.

Comment: ahhh ok, I'll have a play with it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume 2D world (for 3D is almost the same)

when jumping there is no upwards acceleration (unless you have rockets ...)

- instead you accelerate a while feet are still on the ground (for limited time while pressing key)
- after lift off  from ground there are just friction and gravity accelerations
- the jump height depends on escape velocity (when you lift off the ground)

I would do it like this:

```
// globals
struct pnt { float x,y; };
int jump=0; // jump flag
pnt acc; // acceleration [m/s^2]
pnt vel; // velocity [m/s]
pnt pos; // position [m]
float M=75.0; // player mass [kg]
float F=1000.0; // player jump force [N]
float a;
float dt; // time of your timer interval [s]
float tjump;

// init jump on some key hit ... 
jump=1;
acc.x+= F*cos(a)/m; // F/m is the jump strength force / mass
acc.y+= F*sin(a)/m; // a is angle of the jump force
pos.y-= crouch to jump lift off offset; // bigger offset means bigger jump 0.4[m] for example
tjump=0.0;

// integration timer with dt interval
vel+=acc*dt
pos+=vel*dt
if ((jump==1)&&(pos.y>=ground(x).y)) // lift off test
 {
 acc.x= 0.00;
 acc.y=-9.81; // just gravity no movement or jump ...
 jump++;
 }
if ((jump==2)&&(pos.y<=ground(x).y)) // hit the ground test
 {
 acc.y= 0.00;
 vel.y= 0.00;
 pos.y=ground(x).y; // stop on ground
 jump=0; // end of jump
 }
// now for your question add this
if ((jump==2)&&(vel.y>=0)) tjump+=dt; // and at the end tjump will contain the time you want
```

- function: pnt ground(float x); returns the point on the ground for x axis
- if you have more floors than you need  pnt ground(pnt p);
- which return nearest floor ground point downwards from p

If you really need the time then just do this in some for loop instead of timer before the actual jump take place

Comment: Thanks for your response but adding mass and a force to the character and applying a crouch isn't really applicable in my situation.

Comment: it is just an constant which drives the jump strength

Comment: btw. if you have no hills/holes then solving v0 = 0.5*9.81*t*t is your solution t=sqrt(2.0*v0/9.81) where v0 is the y jump start speed

Comment: yeah the character is propelled upwards with a constant acceleration until they hit the max velocity or they let go of the button

Comment: I'm confused lol, doesn't take much! You say that "v0 = 0.5*9.81*t*t is your solution" and then you put another equation that contains v0 so I'm thinking that I find V0 with the first equation you wrote and then you say v0 is the Y start speed?

Comment: @Daniel Holmes v0 is the ground escape speed after upward acceleration stop and t is the time you want ... v0 is known variable and t is the unknown both equations are the same just rewrited to t = ...